# Set a value into input JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to append a text into an input value using jquery, i dont want to use `val()` :

The code :

```
        <span>L'objectif de ce cours est d'introduire</span>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var tb = $("span").text();
                console.log(tb); // L'objectif de ce cours est d'introduire
                $("body").append("<input value='"+tb+"'>");
            });
        </script>
```

but i get just `L` into the input, what is the exact problem, i think the cause is that char `'` , please help me fix it, and thnx !

Comment: i think the 'quotes' is the problem there. The "tb" value is applied before the input is append to body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the type of quotes you're using to delimit the string in JS and the attributes in HTML - you need to swap them over as the value itself contains `'`. Try this:

```
$("body").append('<input value="' + tb + '">');
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c1w124qu/)

Comment: And when the text has a `"` in it? Same issue.

Comment: @epascarello then you would need to escape the value, or use `val()` whcih does the escaping for you. For this issue, it's better to KISS.